# Detect current slide and trigger a function based on that in ANgularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a slider jquery plugin that rotate some images in timer. Its a minified version so i can't read the source. What i wanted to do is everytime the slide change, i want to automatically update an angular model. that model therefore will update some content on the page. How can i make angular track the change triggered by jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Slider probably has some kind of documentation, check that out and look for anything about events. ( jQuery sliders usually broadcast an event on the slider element when things happen - slide change for example )

Then in your code set a listener on your slider event that get's triggered by the event. Inside that listeners callback, change the model, and call $scope.$apply(); if needed.

Example with [slickslider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/):

```
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  yourModel = nextSlide;
});
```

where:

`$('.your-element')` is a selecting the slider element

`beforeChange` is an event that the plugin broadcasts right before it changes the current slide

Comment: You right. FInally I found the docs on the internet. Thanks :)